# LinQ (Language-Integrated Query)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am struggling with an error in the following code using a LinQ statement.

```
Imports System.Linq

Module program
    Sub main()
        Dim a As Integer() = New Integer(9) {100, 30, 50, 40, 20, 70, 80, 90, 10, 60}

        'menampilkan isi array 
        Console.Write("Sumber data{0}: ", vbTab)
        For Each elemen As Integer In a
            Console.Write(elemen & " ")
        Next

        'membuat query
        Dim hasil = From e In a
                    Where e < 60
                    Select e

        Console.Write("{0}Hasil query{1}: ", vbNewLine, vbTab)

        'eksekusi query
        For Each i As Integer In hasil
            Console.Write(i & " ")
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub
End Module
```

And this is one of my error statement :

> Error bc 30451: Name 'where' is not declared.

on the line containing `where e < 60`.

I wonder why `where` should be declared?

Thank you by the way I use vb.net 3.5.

Comment: [Name '<name>' is not declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/name-name-is-not-declared)

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try creating a new project and add in your code and retest.

Comment: You don't need the `Select e`, by the way

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your complete visual studio window, and showing the full error

Comment: The
`Dim a As Integer() = New Integer(9) {100, 30, 50, 40, 20, 70, 80, 90, 10, 60}`
is also rather unusual, commonly one does not specify the size if one provides the elements and vice versa. `Dim a As Integer() = New Integer() {100, 30, 50, 40, 20, 70, 80, 90, 10, 60}` to use long syntax or simpler `Dim a() As Integer = {100, 30, 50, 40, 20, 70, 80, 90, 10, 60}`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I use Vb.net 3.5

Comment: @Caius Jard I think "From and Select" is  Query Sructure ?

Comment: @Caius Jard I am not using  Visual Studio. Just use Command Prompt to compile code

Comment: @Enigmativity What Version of VB.net are you using ?

Comment: @Christoph I will try using your code, Thank you

Comment: @farihanashih - I'm using LINQPad v5.43.

Comment: If this were in Visual Studio you might need `Imports System.Linq`. Not sure how to do this with a command line compilation.

Comment: There is no such thing as VB.NET 3.5. You are targeting version 3.5 of the .NET Framework but that is a different thing. If you were using VS then it would be the same version as that, e.g. .NET 3.5 was first introduced while VB 2008 was current. I've never used the commandline compiler but I guess that would have a version corresponding to the VB version, e.g. VB 2008 was VB 9.

Comment: Have you successfully used LINQ query syntax in this context before? I wonder whether function syntax would work, i.e. `Dim hasil = a.Where(Function(e) e < 60)`.

Comment: By the way, are you aware the VS Community is free and almost on a par with Professional as far as functionality is concerned? If you're using the commandline compiler because you want to then fair enough but if you're doing so because you don't want to pay for VS then that's misguided.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm beggginer at coding. this is my first time using LinQ Structure and i try to make another code use LinQ Statement. The Result is the same, error in Query statement

Comment: I didn't use Visual Studio either: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NEe2LF - but here's a link to visual studio free edition: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ - using notepad and vbc.exe is like tying your arms and legs together, lying down and moving around by dragging yourself along using your chin; slow and painful. Using visual studio is like standing up and going to a run

Comment: @Carius Jard Thank you

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. that code working properly "dim hasil = a.where(function(e) e < 60)". It is just about version.When my code compiled with vb.net 4.0 it's work. But for version v3.5 is your code which work properly